# ngrx entity adapter for a nested property

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-entity

I have the following store structure for users:

```
 usersState = {
    isLoading: boolean;
    items: {
       entities: {},
       ids: []
    }
 }
```

`adapter.getSelectors()` only works for the top level keys, whereas I want to apply it inside the items key. How can that be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From @ngrx/entity - models.d.ts:

```
getSelectors<V>(selectState: (state: V) => EntityState<T>): EntitySelectors<T, V>;
```

You can simply provide a projector to `adapter.getSelectors()` like this:

```
adapter.getSelectors((state: YourStateType) => state.items)
```